# Get by subdocument key, Spring Hibernate MongoDB application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate

I got the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Document(collection = "devices")
public class Device {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "basic_info")
    private Map<String, String> basicInfo;

// getters, setters
```

and the following repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface DeviceRepository extends MongoRepository<Device, Long> {

    List<Device> findByBasicInfo_Name(String name);
```

and the document looks like this:

```
"id": 1,
"basicInfo": {
    "created": "timestamp",
    "name": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "status": "string"
}
```

I am trying to retrieve a document based on the `"name"` key in `"basicInfo"` with the `findByBasicInfo_Name` function, I even tried with `findByBasicInfoName`as someone suggested in another thread without any luck. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type String! Traversed path: Device.basicInfo.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom repository and implement using `mongoTemplate`.

```
@Repository
public interface DeviceRepository extends MongoRepository<Device, String>, DeviceRepositoryCustom {}
```

Make a custom repo interface and declare one method to findByMapKey

```
public interface DeviceRepositoryCustom {

  List<Device> findByMapKey(String mapKey,String value, Class clazz);
}
```

Implement the interface.

```
  public class DeviceRepositoryImpl implements  DeviceRepositoryCustom {

      @Autowired
      private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

      @Override
      public List<Device> findByMapKey(String mapKey,String value, Class clazz) {

      Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("basicInfo."+mapId).is(value));

       return mongoTemplate.find(query,clazz);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this solution helpful to you for this question?